# How to write to Azure storage when the primary region down?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, redundancy

Our application uses RA-GZRS for storage which enables to read data from the secondary when the primary is down, but can't write to it.

Is there a solution which enables application to do both read from and write to storage in the event of an Azure region going down?

Comment: if you need a true active-active storage solution (where you can write to multiple regions), CosmosDB would be your only solution for that

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Storage, there can be only one region (primary) where you can write. The other region (secondary) will always be read only.

One possible solution would be to do a manual failover so that the secondary region of your account becomes the primary and then you should be able to write to it. However, please be aware that the manual failover comes with a lots of caveats and make sure you understand those.

You can read more about those things here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal#important-implications-of-account-failover.

Comment: to keep continuing business, there should be some architectural design to overcome the limitation of writing ONLY primary so that we keep writing to storage even when primary is down. Do you aware anything like that?

Comment: AFAIK, nothing of that sort is available in Azure natively unfortunately. You would need to roll out your own solution IMO.

Comment: The document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/geo-redundant-design?tabs=current#handling-updates-when-running-in-read-only-mode) says "There are many ways to handle update requests when running in read-only mode." what are those many ways?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#redundancy-in-a-secondary-region). To quote from the article:

> If the primary region becomes unavailable, you can choose to fail over
> to the secondary region. After the failover has completed, the
> secondary region becomes the primary region, and you can again read
> **and write data**. For more information on disaster recovery and to learn
> how to fail over to the secondary region, see Disaster recovery and
> storage account failover.

The tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-create-geo-redundant-storage?tabs=dotnet) tells you how to build a highly available application that **automatically** switches between endpoints on a failure. It uses a circuit breaker pattern.

Comment: As per the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-initiate-account-failover?tabs=azure-portal#important-implications-of-account-failover) , "failover after initiation can vary though typically less than one hour". Considering the duration involved in failover process, on primary region down choosing to fail over to the secondary region to overcome the write limitation of RA-GZRS is not suitable for production workload.

Comment: In general to avoid data loss in such situations, storage is not the only persistence mechanism used. You would have the data sitting in a queue (Service Bus) and would have a process pick it up and write it to the storage. All of this needs to be done in a transaction. If there is any problem storing the data, it is still safe in the queue.